# VMware Workstation fails to have access to VMware vSphere server

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-workstation

Since about 10 days access from VMware Workstation 12.7 Pro to VMware vSphere 6.5 server(s) on the same network fails.
After entering the login name and password of the vSphere and clicking on 'connect' the Workstation front-end is being closed immediately.
(The vSphere 6.5 server is working without problems)
BTW Running VM's on the Workstation keep running also after the Workstation front-end has closed itself.
VMware workstation is running on openSUSE 42.2
Who is this problem familiar and has an idea or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour I've got from the Workstation forum at vmware.com
Default VMware Workstation is using the libcurl library of underlaying  operating system. But the libcurl which is used by openSUSE 42.2 is a newer one then the one that VMware Workstation is built for.
One solution is to force VMware Workstation to use his own libcurl version. The (terminal) command for this is: 
export VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_LIBS=force
And then start VMware Workstation

To get this permanent:

Rename the file /usr/bin/vmware and created a new file 'vmware':

```
    mv /usr/bin/vmware /usr/bin/vmware.org
    vi /usr/bin/vmware
```

Paste the next lines in this new made file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    export VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_LIBS=force
    /usr/bin/vmware.org $*
```

Make this new file /usr/bin/vmware executable

Another solution is downgrading the libcurl openSUSE is using. A solution I have not tested.